# Proper way to create more than one object with one POST request using Tastypie and Django

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

Let's say I have two Django models, ModelA and ModelB. The creation of an object of ModelA should trigger in some cases the creation of an object of ModelB. At the moment, without using Tastypie, I have the following view that controls the creation of A-objects:

```
def new_A_created_view(request):
    post_data = json.loads(request.body)
    ... parse post arguments ...

    a = ModelA.objects.create(...)
    if conditions_are_met(...):
       b = ModelB.objects.create(...)
```

Now I want to transition to a REST Api, and using TastyPie I have the following resource:

```
class ModelAResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        ...

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        if bundle.request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
           ...compute objects attributes from received post data ...
```

I am aware of the following options to create the corresponding B object:

1. **Override save or post_save method**. Override save method or add a post_save signal in the ModelA so the creation of the object B follows immediately the act of saving A. Problems I see in this approach:

   - The logic of creating the object ModelB could depend not on attributes present in A, but rather in parameters included in the POST request.
   - I'm losing the nice 'controller' logic in the views.py in favor of a more obscure logic inside the model.
2. **Override Resource.obj_create** in ModelAResource so it creates a ModelA object and a ModelB object (if needed) based on the resource POST information. In this case, I feel as well that the creation of objects is being obscured in some way.

Any solution that I am missing? What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you show us how ModelA and ModelB are declared in `models.py`? Do they both have relations each other?

Comment: In my particular case, ModelA has ModelB as one of its fields. So inside ModelA there would be a field defined as object_b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB). ModelB has no direct relation with ModelA though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I prepended a url in the resource class, overriding the entrance point to the resource and directing it to a custom function of the class that performs all the logic needed. I deleted any hydrating from the resource as well.

```
class ModelAResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = ModelAResource.objects.all()
        authentication = MyOwnAuthentication()
        resource_name = 'modelAResource'
        allowed_methods = ['post']

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('process_resource'), name="process_resource")]

    def process_resource(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        self.is_authenticated(request)

        data = self.deserialize(request, request.body)

        param1 = data.get('param1name', '')
        param2 = data.get('param2name', '')

        ModelA.objects.create(...)
        if it_should_be_done(param1, param2):
            ModelB.objects.create(...)
```

Of course this has its caveats as I have overridden the default url to access the API, but in my case that's not problematic as the API only exposes one operation (creation) on the resource. Anyway, the prepended url could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because ModalA has relation to ModelB, and you want that ModelB is automatically saved when ModelA is saved, your resource declaration should be,

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from yourapp.models import ModelA, ModelB

class ModelAResource(ModelResource):
    model_b = fields.ForeignKey(
        'yourapp.resources.ModelBResource',
        'model_b',
        full=True
    )
    # ....
    class Meta:
        queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
        # ....

class ModelBResource(ModelResource):
    # ....
    class Meta:
        queryset = ModelB.objects.all()
        # ....
```

And when you POST/PUT/PATCH, you just put `model_b` in your data just like you create/edit `model_b`

**for example**,

```
{
    "field1_of_model_a" : "content_of_field1_of_model_a",
    "field2_of_model_a" : "content_of_field2_of_model_a",
    "model_b" : {
        "field_1_of_model_b" : "content_of_field_1_of_model_b",
        "field_2_of_model_b" : "content_of_field_2_of_model_b"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @adityasdarma1, I didn't consider that options although it is not exactly what I wanted to do. ModelB should be created automatically in the server, not received via POST. In order to clarify what I am after, ModelA is just an url and ModelB is the domain of that url plus some statistics. So when one POST to ResourceA is made, I check if the domain object of that url exists in the database and create it if not. I wanted to make the question more general but this is my particular case :).